# Class function usage on html page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a class as x.cs and there is a function

```
 public string telefonReplace(string tel)
    {
        tel = tel.Replace("(", "");
        tel = tel.Replace(")", "");
        tel = tel.Replace(" ", "");

        return tel;
    }
```

when i called it on page.aspx.cs

```
x func = new x();

func.telefonReplace("string value");
```

I can use this but i want to use it on html page like;

```
<div><%# func.telefonReplace(Eval["someting"])%> <div>
```

But i can't call this function. How can i make it ?

Comment: You _could_ expose it as a [page method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.enablepagemethods(v=vs.110).aspx) but why don't you simply add a JavaScript function with that piece of logic?

Comment: I don't know JavaScript. @khlr

Comment: Have a quick online search. You'll figure it out :-) It's no rocket science to put that into a js function.

Comment: Yes, actually you are right. :) @khlr

Answer (score 1):

The reason this isn't working is because HTML works on the clients side while your functions written in C# run in the server, so you need to link your html function call to the code behind, and this can be done using an event in html like the click of a button or something similar, here is an example:

```
<div id="Replace" OnMouseOver="<%# func.telefonReplace(Eval["someting"]) %>" runat="server">

<a href="#" runat="server" onServerClick="MyFuncion" />
```

This should make the call to your function. Another approach if you do not want to link the call of your function to a user event, is to use javaScript to run your functionality when the page loads, there is lots of documentation on the web about this.

Hope this helps